# Scrapy display response.request.url inside zip()

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to create a simple Scrapy function which will loop through a set of standard URLs and pull their Alexa Rank. The output I want is just two columns: One showing the scraped Alexa Rank, and one showing the URL which was scraped.

Everything seems to be working except that I cannot get the scraped URL to display correctly in my output. My code currently is:

```
import scrapy

class AlexarSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'AlexaR'
    #Will update allowed domains and start URL once I fix this problem
    start_urls = ['http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/google.com/', 
    'https://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/reddit.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        rank = response.css(".rankmini-rank::text").extract()
        url_raw = response.request.url
    
        #extract content into rows
        for item in zip(url_raw,rank):
            scraped_info = {
                str('url_raw') : item[0],
                'rank' : item[1]
            }

        yield scraped_info
```

And then when run, the code outputs a table showing:

[AlexaRank Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eusbY.png)

| url_raw | rank |
| --- | --- |
| h |  |
| t | 21 |
| t |  |
| h |  |
| t | 1 |
| t |  |

These are the correct scraped rankings (21 and 1) but the url_raw field is showing "h" or "t", rather than the actual URL string value. I've tried converting the url_raw variable to a string with no luck.

How can I set the variable up such that it displays the correct URL?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `zip()` takes 'rank' which is a list and 'url_raw' which is a string so you get a character from 'url_raw' for each iteration.

Solution with cycle:

```py
import scrapy
from itertools import cycle


class AlexarSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'AlexaR'
    #Will update allowed domains and start URL once I fix this problem
    start_urls = ['http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/google.com/',
                  'https://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/reddit.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        rank = response.css(".rankmini-rank::text").extract()
        url_raw = response.request.url
        #extract content into rows
        for item in zip(cycle([url_raw]), rank):
            scraped_info = {
                str('url_raw'): item[0],
                'rank': item[1]
            }
            yield scraped_info
```

Solution with list:

```py
import scrapy


class AlexarSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'AlexaR'
    #Will update allowed domains and start URL once I fix this problem
    start_urls = ['http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/google.com/',
                  'https://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/reddit.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        rank = response.css(".rankmini-rank::text").extract()
        url_raw = [response.request.url for i in range(len(rank))]
        #extract content into rows
        for item in zip(url_raw, rank):
            scraped_info = {
                str('url_raw'): item[0],
                'rank': item[1]
            }
            yield scraped_info
```